# Sveltekit slug in the rootfolder and build static site

Tags: slug, sveltekit

I have the following structure inside my routes folder

```
+ Angststoornis
+ Doelgroep
+ Prijs
+ Selectief-mutisme
[locationName].svelte
index.svelte
```

Where the [locationName] slug is dealing with the localized landing pages (for example https://domain.be/gent, where gent is the name of a local city). Another route is for example (https://domain.be/Selectief-mutisme) This route should not be handled by the [locationName] slug, but by /Selectief-mutisme/index.svelte. Let's call these "hard coded" routes

With my development setup everything works great. However when i try to build my site with the static adapter it crashes on the fact that it tries to build /Selectief-mutisme on the [locationName] slug route instead of /Selectief-mutisme/index.svelte. Some hard-coded routes are getting exported correctly but now I can't seem to overcome the /Selectief-mutisme route.

I have tried renaming the [locationName] slug to [zLocationName] because the documentation mentions that dynamic routes are being checked alphabetically if there are multiple options available. But to no avail. (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#routing-advanced-fallthrough-routes)

Does anyone in here has an idea how to solve this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you have a load function in that folder that doesn't return anything while building.  If a route does that it will go to the 'next' matching route.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for looking into this. I have spend some additional time into this issue. I changed the first letter of a folder into a lowercase letter a while ago. Since github doesnt update changes in capitals. The catch all route Will indeed be called because it Cant find the route.